# Preventing over-segmentation with water-shedding algorithm

Tags: python, image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have a shape like the following: [image]

Here is my current solution:

```
im = imread('im.tif');
bw = im2bw(im, 0.1);
D = bwdist(~bw);
D = -D;
D(~bw) = Inf;
L = watershed(D, 8);
L(~bw) = 0;
rgb = label2rgb(L,'jet',[0 0 0]);
bw = im2bw(rgb, 0);
imshow(bw);
```

This produces: [image]

However, I'm not sure how to get rid of the dissections on singular intact blobs, for instance, the upper right one is dissected into 2 pieces, when it shouldn't be dissected at all. I was looking for some thresholding within the watershed function. But wasn't successful. The default (and lowest) thresholding is 4 connected components and that's what the above code uses. Even with that, it segments whole blobs. Is there a way to fine tune this even more?

Comment: In what form do you have access to your shapes? Just the image?

Comment: Have a look at the MATLAB toturials, there are few examples that may be useful to your case: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/image-analysis.html

Comment: Yes, I only have the images(.tif format). I wish it was generated manually, then I could just use the coordinate files. :/

Comment: see https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/

Comment: Wow, I actually stumbled upon the watershed technique 30 minutes ago! I experimented with it and posted my results. @sturkmen